# Jackson desearialize a list of Strings coming from Redis as a generic type

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I have a piece of Kotlin code that looks like this:

```
val objs = results.map {
            if(it == null) return@map null
            val typeRef: TypeReference<T> = object : TypeReference<T>() {}
            jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(it, typeRef)
        }
```

I want my method to return a List<T?> where T is a generic type in the signature of the code.

While it "kinda" works, its not specifically what I am looking for.
For instance, when I call my method like this :

```
 myMethod<MyDTO>get(keys: List<String>) // ---> I want to get a list of MyDTO
```

the methods returns a list of LinkedHashMap instead of a list of MyDTO.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have just found a way.

I can pass an extra parameter to my method:

```
ofClass: Class<T>
```

So my method now looks like this:

```
 val objs = results.map {
            if(it == null) return@map null
            jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(it, ofClass)
        }
```

and carry the type information with it.

Works like charm.